# Como serializar um Json em Objeto? Delphi XE7

Tags: json, delphi

Eu preciso gerar um Objeto que representa um arquivo JSON e o Delphi está me gerando o seguinte

ERRO: 
'Internal: Invalid pair name {"diretorio":"d:\Pasta\Doc"}: expected type or ref'

Na linha de código:

```
  objetoJson := UnMar.UnMarshal(oJson) as TJson;
```

Alguém saberia me dizer qual o problema e como resolver, por favor?

```
program Project2;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses   System.SysUtils, Data.DBXJSONReflect, JSON;

type
  TJson = CLass
    diretorio: string;
  end;

var
  oJson: TJSONObject;
  objetoJson: TJson;
  UnMar: TJSONUnMarshal;
begin
  try
// Crio o Json
oJson := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(TEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes('{"diretorio": "d:\\Pasta\\Doc"}'),0) as TJSONObject;
// Mostra o conteudo no Json no console
Writeln('Conteudo do objeto Json: '+ojson.ToString);
UnMar := TJSONUnMarshal.Create;
try
  // Tento repassar o Objeto de Json para a Classe
  objetoJson := UnMar.UnMarshal(oJson) as TJson;
  try
    writeln(  objetoJson.diretorio);

  finally
    objetoJson.Free;
  end;
finally
  UnMar.Free;
end;
  except
on E: Exception do
begin
  Writeln('Erro ao tentar usar UmMarshal: ');
  Writeln( E.Message);
end;
  end;
  readln;
end.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objetos em object pascal são tipados, por isso você precisa incluir algumas referências dentro do JSON para que o processo de `UnMarshal` possa identificar o `ID` e o `REF`.

Segue exemplo do JSON que deve ser passado:

```
'{"type":"Project2.TJsonOBJ","id":1,"fields":{"diretorio":""}}'
```